# View the year questions are posted and be able to sort questions by votes regardless of year?

Tags: support, user-interface

I'd like to be able to view the year questions are posted.

And to be able to sort questions by votes regardless of year.

I see questions in the right hand side mention how many years ago they were asked, and I could do a subtraction to find what year they were posted.. but it'd be more memorable if the year was mentioned and not just the day and date.  I saw it in one question.  maybe 'cos a community wiki https://superuser.com/questions/2/free-antivirus-solutions-for-windows  but normally I don't see a year.

**{OK, the one above is answered, thanks. How about below }**

Also
I just clicked on questions and votes, got them ordered by votes, but I don't think it went across years 'cos the questions that came up are recent ones with high votes. Not older ones like the early that got lots of votes like some of the early "subjective" questions one post per feature/application, that got lots of answers and were good as references.

So is it possible to see top questions for older years , and across years?

Comment: If you hover over the date seen on a post you'll see a tooltip showing the full date and time

Answer (score 5):

Simply mouse over the time on almost any date on the site and you will get UTC time in the tooltip.

Also, the year *always* appears once a year boundary has been crossed (e.g. question was posted in Dec and it is now Jan).

[image: date tooltip hover]

Comment: in the second part of my question what I mean, if I click votes, highest votes come first which is good, but it looks a bit like maybe it's only showing this year's top ones.